# Не удается найти файл включения "corecrt.h": no such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Создал Hello World в только что установленной Microsoft VS 2015. При попытке компиляции HelloWorld выдает ошибку.

Код:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
int main(void) { 
    cout << "HelloWorld"; 
    return 0; 
}
```

Ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что делать?

Comment: Это сообщения Intellisense. А вы компиляцию хоть запускали? И покажите ваш код.

Comment: И какой вы выбрали тип проекта?

Comment: Консольное приложение. Для запуска нажал кнопку с зеленой стрелкой - локальный отладчик.

Comment: Убедитесь, что путь (вместо звездочек цифры) `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.*.*\ucrt` у вас в  `include path` (посмотрите в настройках проекта). Если так, то проверьте, что по этому пути есть `corecrt.h`.

Comment: Как я понял не прописан какой-то IncludePath, но как его прописать?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian h-файлы там есть, я проверил. А куда именно нужно прописать? Я прописал в свойствах проекта C++ -> Общие ->Каталоги включаемых файлов.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian вроде бы начало собираться, но вдруг появилась ошибка "не удается открыть файл "ucrtd.lib".

Comment: @user5483163 теперь то же самое для путей библиотек сделайте.

Comment: @user5483163 но в целом, вручную всего этого делать не требуется, достаточно только поставить галку `Inherit from parent or project defaults` для include и lib путей.

Comment: Консольное приложение нативное или C++/CLI?

Comment: А что делать, если corecrt.h нет по тому пути, что вы указали?

Comment: @Aster преобразовал ваш ответ в комментарий. )